# Isolating Parts of a Localized Date

Tags: javascript, date

Regardless of what timezone the user's computer is in, I need to determine what the current date is in Hawaii, and if it is before or after 1pm.

This gets me close:

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone:'Pacific/Honolulu'});
```

Outputs: `11/27/2017, 5:18:58 PM`

But what's the best way to isolate the different sections?

- I'm inclined to parse the string back as a date to allow me to get things like getHours() but that seems to be turning a date into a string back into a date.
- Breaking apart the string seems clunky.
- Things like `new Date().getHours().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone:'Pacific/Honolulu'})` don't work.

Comment: It's not clear what you want: "this brings me close" - close to what ?

Comment: This would be entirely dependent upon the TZ in which the client received the date and what TZ you need the date to be in.

Comment: The options to *toLocaleString* allow you to do that. There are other ways to get the time for a particular time zone and to format a date (so many duplicates).

Comment: Honolulu is always UTC -10, no daylight saving so all you need to do is create a (local) *Date*, subtract 10 hours using *setUTCHours*, then format your date string using UTC methods. Done.